# my button can't handle a click event all it says is "'btnLogin_click' cannot handle event 'click' because they do not have a compatable signiture"

Tags: vb.net, button

I keep getting an error saying method 'btnLogin_click' cannot handle event `Click` because they do not have a compatible signature.

If anyone has some insight as to why its doing this, please enlighten me.

```
    Public Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs, messageBox As MessageBox) Handles btnLogin.Click

        Dim strUser As String = txtUser.Text
        Dim strpass As String = txtPass.Text

        If (strUser = "drake" And strpass = ("1")) Then
            MessageBox.Show("This is where we take the user to the bard lounge.")

        ElseIf Not (strUser = "drake" And strpass = ("1")) Then
            txtPass.Text = ("") And MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username and/or password.")
        End If


    End Sub
```

This was supposed to be a simple login screen to open a windows form if you use the right username and password. I made this by following a tutorial for a login screen from youtube, and then optimizing the code as much as possible, with some help from my uncle who is a coding veteran of 20 years.

Once I got it cleaned up, I started working on my own features. I tried to make the `txtPass` text box clear itself if the pass/user were incorrect upon clicking the login button `btnLogin`. But as soon as I try to run the program it gives me an error that didn't show up in the development tab before. I already attempted to use `Clear()` rather than `txtPass.text = ""` however it only gave me more errors I couldn't understand.

Comment: The method signature of the `Click` event is defined by the `System.EventHandler` delegate which is defined like this: `public delegate void EventHandler(object? sender, EventArgs e);`. Unless your method has a compatible signature then it cannot handle the `Click` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the `Button` that is the problem but your code. When an event is raised, the object raising the event calls the method registered as the event handler. You can't just put whatever parameters you want in that method. In your case, how is the `Button` supposed to pass an argument for that third parameter when the person who wrote the code for the `Button` class years ago had no idea that parameter would exist? You're not even using that parameter inside the method anyway, so what is it for? Just change the method declaration to what it should have been in the first place and it will work:

```vb
Public Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
```

That's what would have been generated in the first place if you had just double-clicked the `Button` in the designer. You can't arbitrarily add parameters to an event handler. The object raising the event expects a specific signature so your method has to have that signature.

Comment: Long story short, remove the message box parameter. Good practice, let visual studio generate your function signatures when possible.